# Animate UserControl Elements from Outside

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, user-controls

I have a custom UserControl which implements the following animations:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <QuinticEase Core:Key="EasingInOut" EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
    <Storyboard Core:Key="AnimationHide">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="m_Front" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Duration="00:00:00.1" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EasingInOut}" To="0"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="m_Back" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" BeginTime="00:00:00.1" Duration="00:00:00.1" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EasingInOut}" To="1"/>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard Core:Key="AnimationShow">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="m_Back" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" BeginTime="00:00:00.0" Duration="00:00:00.1" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EasingInOut}" To="0"/>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="m_Front" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" BeginTime="00:00:00.1" Duration="00:00:00.1" EasingFunction="{StaticResource EasingInOut}" To="1"/>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And has the following structure:

```
<Canvas>
    <Grid Core:Name="m_Front" Height="{Core:Static Namespace:Card.RealHeight}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="{Core:Static Namespace:Card.RealWidth}">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0"/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Image Core:Name="m_FrontImage" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Source={Core:Static Properties:Resources.Fronts}, Converter={StaticResource ImagesConverter}}" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Core:Name="m_FrontClipping"/>
            </Image.Clip>
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform Core:Name="m_FrontTranslation"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Core:Name="m_Back" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform/>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="{Binding Source={Core:Static Properties:Resources.Back}, Converter={StaticResource ImagesConverter}}" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

If I run one of those animations in the UserControl code behind everything works absolutely fine:

```
Storyboard show = (Storyboard)Resources["AnimationShow"];
show.Begin();
```

Now... I was trying to simulate that animation from outside the UserControl itself (in my MainWindow.cs code behind to be exact):

```
DoubleAnimation animationKick1 = new DoubleAnimation();
animationKick1.BeginTime = beginTime;
animationKick1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.125D);
animationKick1.To = 0D;
animationKick1.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, myUC.m_Front);
animationKick1.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, CreatePropertyPath("RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));

DoubleAnimation animationKick2 = new DoubleAnimation();
animationKick2.BeginTime = beginTime;
animationKick2.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.125D);
animationKick2.To = 1D;
animationKick2.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetProperty, myUC.m_Back);
animationKick2.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, CreatePropertyPath("RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
```

But nothing happens... why? How can I animate UserControl elements from outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off just exposing a method on your UserControl to run the animation.  You're probably running into some scoping issues with your property paths.  Trying to access the internals of a user control from your main window doesn't really follow the basic principals of encapsulation.  Is there a compelling reason to keep the animation code in MainWindow?

Comment: +1 for `Trying to access the internals of a user control from your main window doesn't really follow the basic principals of encapsulation.`

Comment: The compelling reason is that Timeline class is one of the worst class ever developed in .NET libraries with one of the poorest events selection ever seen. In my MainWindow, I should create an animation that moves some custom UserControls simultaneously (Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top) WHILE my UserControls animate themselves using the animations in my post... so, unless I find a way to merge those Storyboards together (which would need a big rewriting of my code) or to implement a Started event on Timeline, I have to find a workaround.