# Activate storyboard from UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls, windows-phone

**EDIT: It appears that any call which results in the UI being changed doesn't fire properly. This includes storyboards, things that change text values, etc.**

I have a usercontrol which I have created, called NewsArticle, which is used to populate a page with news articles. This is functioning properly. However, the problems began to arise when i attempted to attach a tap event to the usercontrol, which created a method inside the usercontrol's code behind.

Being that the code I need to fire is located in my MainPage.xaml's code behind, I did the following:

```
MainPage mp = new MainPage();
mp.ScrapePage(lnk);
```

What this does is fire the method "ScrapePage" with the paramerer "lnk" which is a string value.

The method fires, but it only executes a messagebox I have setup to show that the method is actually firing.

However, these lines do not work:

```
((Storyboard)Resources["Loading"]).Begin();
((Storyboard)Resources["Article_in"]).Begin();
```

The storyboards I am trying to activate are located in my MainPage.xaml resources, not my Usercontrol. The method that contains the above lines is in MainPage.xaml, but fired from NewsArticle.xaml, a usercontrol embedded on MainPage.xaml.

**To clarify, these storyboards work fine when the method that activates the storyboards is fired from MainPage.xaml.**

Comment: you are creating a second MainPage with your New statement therefore the code is not running on your Parent Form. Try setting the Parent Property of your UserControl and use that to access your Parent Form.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out with help from Mark Hall's comment. Posting the awnser here for future reference:

```
    StackPanel stp = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as StackPanel;
    ScrollViewer sc = stp.Parent as ScrollViewer;
    Grid gr = sc.Parent as Grid;
    Grid gr2 = gr.Parent as Grid;
    MainPage mp = gr2.Parent as MainPage;
    ((Storyboard)mp.Resources["Article_in"]).Begin();
```

Basically, just work your way down the visual tree to the MainPage, then try to initialize the animation off of it. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this piece of code instead of your `Storyboard` code?

```
Storyboard show = (Storyboard)Resources["Loading"];
show.Begin();
```

This one might be helpful!

[Animate UserControl Elements from Outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277734/)